# Display Binary data as an image

Tags: ajax, image, reactjs, binary, binary-data

My binary image is in DB on an address: http://localhost:8000/pictures/f31289ae-0491/data

I'm using React and I would like to display image on the page

I know there is a lot of similar questions, but I couldn't find solution to my problem.

[image: png Image example]

Comment: try this: [binary data to image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41972435/how-to-convert-the-binary-data-to-image-in-reactjs)

Comment: I tried that but still without success, and with error invalid url

Comment: can you create a fiddle and put the binary data in a variable use the same the way suggested in the another answer, because it should work.

Comment: That would be something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/perija/bhd1kom3/7/

This.state.image I'm getting from db

Comment: i think, that data is not base64, check this ques for same data: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29343196/how-to-convert-base64-to-image-by-using-jquery