# How to convert data binary into image in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, react-native, axios

I'm already trying this, but it still not working for me
[how to convert the binary data to image in reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41972435/how-to-convert-the-binary-data-to-image-in-reactjs)

here my code

```
        return axios.post(`${API_MOBILE}/${path}`, formData, {
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            },
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            if (error.response) {
                return Promise.reject({
                    message: error.response.data.error,
                    code: error.response.status
                });
            } else if (error.request) {
              console.log(error.request);
              throw error;
            } else {
              console.log('Error', error.message);
              throw error;
            }
        });
    },
```

here the controller

```
try {
        let { detail } = yield select(state => state.user);
        const result = yield call(API.generateMotif, payload, detail.api_token);
        
        yield put({
            type: types.GENERATE_MOTIF_SUCCESS,
            payload: result,
        });

    } catch (err) {
        yield put(handleError(err));

        yield put({
            type: types.GENERATE_MOTIF_FAILURE,
            payload: err,
        });
    }
```

and here my frontend

```
<div className="box-body">
                        { props.uploading 
                            ? (
                                <div>
                                    <img src={props.image} alt="upload placeholder"/>
                                    <Spinner />
                                </div>
                            )
                            
                            : props.generated !== ''
                                ? <img src={"data:;base64,"+props.generated} alt="generated motif"/>
                                : <AddPhotoAlternate className="icon-large"/>
                        }
                    </div>

GenerateM.propTypes = {
    image: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    generated: PropTypes.string,
    list: PropTypes.array,
    uploading: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    imageChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};
```

In my console, `generated` has data binary, so I found solutions in that link that I post, but it still not working for me. Response that I want, in my frontend show image, but here the response that I got
it just snippet of response that I copying from Postman, when I copying from my console it just has copying nothing.
`����JFIF��C    $.' ",#(7),01444'9=82<.342��C  2!!22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222��"�� ���}!1AQa"q2���#B��R��$3br� %&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz��������������������������������������������������������������������������� ���w!1AQaq"2�B���� #3R�br�`
like in this picture
[image]

did you have any solutions that can help me? please, any suggestion will be very helpful for me.

Comment: Have you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42395034/how-to-display-binary-data-as-image-in-react)

Comment: yes, I'm trying that using responsetype blob, and still not working, the image still not shown. I put `{responseType: 'blob'}` in `return.axios()`, and change `<img src={"data:;base64,"+props.generated} alt="generated motif"/>` into `<img src={URL.createObjectURL(props.generated)} alt="generated motif" />`

Comment: @jhon were you able to resolve the issue? I am also facing the same problem but unable to fix it even after following the same steps defined here.

Comment: @bubble-cord I just pass response to img file type. There is no wrong in my code, but it doesn't work because response in my blob already decode using ```base64_decode()``` . When I changing response with only using ```base64_encode()```, using ```"data:'base64,"+[props.generated``` will work

Comment: @jhon Can you please take a look at my query and suggest the changes that I need to implement accordingly?

Comment: @bubble-cord sorry for late response, do you still have an issue for your code?

Comment: @jhon yea. Still the same

Comment: @bubble-cord you can post a question, and write the code. I will try to solve your question. send the link to me

Comment: @jhon https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63887436/display-an-image-returned-by-mockserver-on-a-web-page-using-react. Here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```html
<img src={`data:image/*;base64,${props.generated}`} alt="generated motif" />
```

But you must ensure response from your API is something that can be decoded.

See PHP's [`base64_encode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) and [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42399865/11722883).