# Display an image returned by MockServer on a web page using React?

Tags: reactjs, base64, rest, mockserver

I am using Mock Server with OPEN API 3.0 to mock data & expectations. I need to fetch a dummy image using Mock Server as per the given sample on:

https://www.mock-server.com/mock_server/getting_started.html#button_response_literal_binary_PNG_body

I have the function definition with my swagger/ Open API swagger editor something like this:

```
/geo/{geo-id}:
    get:
      description: Geographic information
      tags: [caseload]
      parameters:
      - in: path
        name: geo-id
        required: true
        schema:
          type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: >
            Sample geographic map image in PNG format
          content:
            image/png:
              schema:
                type: string
                format: binary
```

With the sample REST API example as provided on the above link, I created my own mock data expectation CURL request like:

```
curl -v -X PUT "http://localhost:1080/mockserver/expectation" -d '{
  "id": "geo-map",
  "httpRequest": {
    "method" : "GET",
    "path": "/geo/geoid-map"
  },
  "httpResponse": {
    "statusCode": 200,
    "headers": {
      "content-type": ["image/png"],
      "content-disposition": ["form-data; name=\"test.png\"; filename=\"test.png\""]
    },
    "body": {
      "type": "BINARY",
      "base64Bytes": "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....[trimmed]
    }
  }
}'
```

Now, when I execute the request endpoint on the postman,

`http://localhost:1080/geo/geoid-map`, I am successfully able to fetch an image. But when trying the same on my react web app, the response returned by the API produces a console response:

[image: axios.response]

On expanding the `response.data`, it shows binary data something like:

[image]

Passing this binary image into react's `src` is unable to display the image.

Even after following config, as suggested in [how to convert the binary data to image in reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41972435/how-to-convert-the-binary-data-to-image-in-reactjs) & [How to display binary data as image in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42395034/how-to-display-binary-data-as-image-in-react), it does not work.

Any help regarding the same is appreciated

Comment: ```<img src={`data:image/png;base64,${binary_data}`} />``` did you try this?

Comment: In my case, I'm just saving response and write it into a file. Like in PHP code, ```$res = $response->getBody()->getContent(); $file = $res.'.PNG';```

Comment: It can happen because when you get response from ```http://localhost:1080/mockserver/expectation``` response is not PNG type, but base64_decode type, so you must make some controller to handle response from  your API

Comment: @jhon Maybe you're right. Can you help me with some hints on how to convert the response from API?